# OneNote Notebook Notes not in Team Site search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, team-sites, onenote

We have a (hosted O365) SharePoint instance with team sites.

In team sites, when I search I'm not seeing results from within the shared OneNote Notebook. Is it possible to make the site search index all notes and include them in search results?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me!

It does. I just didn't give it enough time to index the notes it seems. I was expecting that to happen a lot more quickly than it did so will chekc if I can alter that.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint in Microsoft 365 also supports the following: .one.

You can wait for the full crawl, then search again.

Default crawled file name extensions and parsed file types in SharePoint Server for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-crawled-file-name-extensions-and-parsed-file-types

Besides, Search results missing in SharePoint Online for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-results-missing